# Angular POST request

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, codeigniter

I have developed an web page using Angular JavaScript. Now it working on web API but when i connect to PHP CodeIgniter API, GET function works but POST method is not working. It responds "Response code 405".

Code for userMaintainenceService:

```
angular.module('commom.services')
 .factory("userMaintainenceService["$resource","appSettings",userMaintainenceSe‌​rvice]); 

function userMaintainenceService($resource,appSettings){
 return $resource(appSettings.serverPath+"dbu/User",null, { 
  Create: { method: 'POST' } 
 });
};
```

Comment: you better post some code if you want help it will be easier

Comment: please add what u have implemented so far

Comment: Code for services

angular.module('commom.services',['ngResource'])
.constant("appSettings",{
 serverPath:"http://10.6.1.41/"
});

Comment: Code for userMaintainenceService 

angular.module('commom.services')
.factory("userMaintainenceService",["$resource","appSettings",userMaintainenceService]);

function userMaintainenceService($resource,appSettings){
return $resource(appSettings.serverPath+"dbu/User",null,
{
    Create:{method:'POST'}
});
};

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you want to CRUD with Angular and CodeIgniter, you can use `$http` from Angular, and a CodeIgniter Webservice

Comment: This is my API's request and response :-

https://1drv.ms/i/s!AoW5Avxu8-UWgmRnrGZIff6Qvalp

(API logic :- API respond the same text as supplied on body )

Answer (score 1):

code 405 tells that the data you are sending with your request is not compatible with API.

from angular http set the proper type (like" "application/xml", etc)which is allowed at your API

Comment: Can u tell where i should specify ( "application/xml") using angular resources.

Comment: This is my API request and respond.

https://1drv.ms/i/s!AoW5Avxu8-UWgmRnrGZIff6Qvalp

Answer (score 0):

In your comments on question I can see you are trying to make a request on:

```
{ return $resource(appSettings.serverPath+"dbu/User",null
```

And in link posted (snapshot) the URL seems to be different:

```
10.6.1.41/dbu/Test
```

If you can provide more details like your full controller/service code snippet. It might help to provide a better solution.

Comment: Can u please provide us a sample Angular project to call that API (10.6.1.41/dbu/Test).

Comment: You just need to change URL. I think that should work.

Comment: Can I get your skype id  Mr. Jayesh ?? so that I can share my screen with you.